# Building a web service with Pyramid

Tags: python, web-services, pyramid

I am a beginner trying to learn how to build a RESTful web service with Pyramid web framework. I am familiar with the basics of Web services and I have experience building them in Java. I plan on not using web service builders like Cornice.
Is there anything specific I have to add in the route configurations?
Can someone please tell me where to start or give any useful links for learning to build web services with Pyramid?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
@view_defaults(route_name='myservice')
class MyServiceView(object):

    def __init__(self, request):
        self.request = request

    @view_config(request_method='GET')
    def get(self):
        return Response(u'This is the GET view')

    @view_config(request_method='POST')
    def post(self):
        return Response(u'This is the POST view')

    @view_config(request_method='PUT')
    def put(self):
        return Response(u'This is the PUT view')

    @view_config(request_method='DELETE')
    def delete(self):
        return Response(u'This is the DELETE view')
```

Comment: How do I get to know what request method is being passed? Is it to be mentioned in my query string?

Comment: @Tania - I think from inside each method you can call `self.request.method`.  However, each method is only called if it matches a particular value already, so there's not much point in looking at it again (ie the `get` method is only called if `self.request.method == 'GET'`)